# duplicates in array with condition of value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[Monogplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jBTUqed0_qV)

I have the following document with an array (names `gists`). Example of a document:

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36ef"),
    "car_id": 78,
    "terminal": "JFK",
    "gists": [
      "A",
      "M",
      "C",
      "D",
      "Q",
      "J",
      "F"
    ]
  },
```

My objective is to query for all documents that have a duplicated "A" in them and get their `car_id`.

While I can find duplicates, I couldn't get the results of "A" in `gists`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "gists": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$gists"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "cid": "$gists"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "count": {
            "$gt": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "gists": "A"  **//<---- this is where I get it off. Gist must contain A in the array**
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "gists": {
        "$addToSet": "$_id.cid"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$expr` expression operator with aggregation operators,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `gists` array and check for value "A"
- `$size` to get total elements from above filtered result
- `$gt` to check above size is greater than 1
- `$group` by null and construct the array of `car_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$gists",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this", "A"] }
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      car_id: { $push: "$car_id" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yswdVFh_Z3D)

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "car_id": [79, 80]
  }
]
```